# Python object oriented Fixed Account

Tags: python

I need the savings account not to be changed into a value that is less than 500. The constructor balance should not accept any values below 500. The code runs well and is okay. The deposit and withdraw methods work correctly but I cannot figure out how to prevent a variable whose balance is less than 500 from accessing the savings account.

```
class BankAccount(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def withdraw(self):
        pass

    def deposit(self):
        pass


class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=500):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposit):
        if self.deposit > 0:
            self.balance += deposit
            return self.balance
        else:
            return "Invalid deposit amount"

    def withdraw(self, withdraw):
        if self.balance < withdraw:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        elif (self.balance - withdraw) < 500:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the minimum account balance"
        elif withdraw < 0:
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw
            return self.balance


class CurrentAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=0):
        self.balance = balance

    def deposit(self, deposit):
        if self.deposit > 0:
            self.balance += deposit
            return self.balance
        else:
            return "Invalid deposit amount"

    def withdraw(self, withdraw):
        if withdraw < 0:
            return "Invalid withdraw amount"
        elif self.balance < withdraw:
            return "Cannot withdraw beyond the current account balance"
        else:
            self.balance -= withdraw
            return self.balance
```

Comment: So you want it to be impossible to create a new `SavingsAccount(balance=499)`? Why not add something like `if balance < 500: raise BalanceTooLowError()` to your `SavingsAccount` `__init__`?

Comment: @KernelPanic that is exactly what i want.....let me try it and i will get back to you

Comment: cool :) posted it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class SavingsAccount(BankAccount):
    def __init__(self, balance=500):
        if balance < 500:
            raise ValueError("SavingsAccount balance must be at least 500")
        self.balance = balance
```

You could also define a custom exception:

```
class BalanceTooLowError(ValueError):
    """Raise if attempting to set an account balance to a disallowed value"""
```

Comment: thanks alot i am not an expert yet..the problem i was trying to return a message but the __init__ method should not return anything... I am going to read more on raise and errors.

Comment: I appreciate. I am researching on it and hopefully i will get more answers. Have checked it